# Why would Objective-C require a post-2010 Mac?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos

I'm thinking of signing up for the Objective-C Crash Course on Udemy but the requirement is a Mac after 2010.

I have an early 2009 with 2 x 3.32 GHz Quad-Core Intel Xeon 64 GB 1066 MHz DDR3 ECC & ssHD happily running El Capitan v10.11.6 & running Xcode beta 8.5

Is there something that I'm missing? Is it a hardware thing?
(Please forgive me if this is a really dumb question but I'm a newb in diapers.)

Comment: This question is off-topic for stack overflow. Try asking in a more appropriate site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Udemy may have other reasons for requiring a more recent Mac that is specific to their course.. If you can run El Capitan, you can install the latest Xcode and can use it to learn Objective-C. I would suggest ignoring the requirement for the course until if and when it becomes clear why it's in place.

Comment: I see you're new to Stack Overflow. If you like an answer, you can click the up arrow to indicate so, and if you believe an answer is *the* answer to your question, you can click the checkbox.

Comment: i'm too new for my upvote to count but i clicked the checkmark. thank you once again for your advice.